# Batch program - delete all dividing symbols in numbers

Tags: batch-file

I have a homework task which needed to be done using just batch script. I need to rewrite all the numbers in `.txt` file if they have dividing symbols `.` or `,` but those strings may contain both words and numbers. Also the result should stay in the same file.

For example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 12.3254
2556,4646 ex commodo
```

would become

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 123254
25564646 ex commodo
```

I started with some code that looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

SET verfile=%1

FOR /f "tokens=* delims= " %%A IN (%verfile%) DO (
    SET "Var=%%A"    
    FOR /l %%i IN (0, 1, 9) DO (    
        echo !Var! | findstr "."     
        IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (

    )
)
```

And now I have no idea how to continue it.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Just in case you missed it, in your submitted part code, `%ERRORLEVEL%` should be `!ERRORLEVEL!`, or the line changed to `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory and filename are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q73553463.txt"

:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%b In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%b="

SET /a linecount=0

:: Read entire file into memory

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 rem next line number
 SET /a linecount +=1
 rem record in memory
 SET "#!linecount!=%%e"
)

:: process each line removing [,.] following a digit
:: and report to original file
(
FOR /L %%e IN (1,1,%linecount%) DO (
 FOR %%c IN ("." ",") DO FOR /L %%y IN (0,1,9) DO SET "#%%e=!#%%e:%%y%%~c=%%y!"
 ECHO !#%%e!
)
)>"%filename1%"

TYPE "%filename1%"

GOTO :EOF
```

The `set #` command will generate a list like

```
#whatever=something
#whateverelse=somethingelse
```

for all variables that are currently set and start `#`.**BUT** it would be unusual to have any variable set that starts `#` so `set` would generate an error. The `2^>nul` sends any error-report (on standard device *stderr*, which is device `2`) to `nul` that is, nowhere. The caret `^` is required because `cmd` needs to distinguish between a part of the `set` command and a part of the `for`.

The for/f...%%b using `delims` of `=` generates "tokens" from the list generated by the `set`. Tokens are separated by any sequence of any of the delimiters specified between `=` and `"`, and by default, "token1" is selected, so the strings applied to `%%b` are

```
#whatever
#whateverelse
```

and these variables need to be set to *nothing*.

See `for /?` from the prompt for documentation on `for` or browse thousands of examples on SO.

Use `set "var=value"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces which can cause chaos. Once bitten, twice shy.

Then we read the file. Using `"delims="` sets no delimiters, hence the whole line forms "token 1" which is assigned to `%%e`. The `usebackq` changes the meaning of `"` so that a double-quoted filename may be used. The filename I've used includes a <kbd>Space</kbd> but if there are no separator characters in the name, the quotes and `usebackq` can be omitted (again, ref `for/?`)

Then add 1 to the linecount and record the line in memory by assigning it to `#!linecount!`. The `!linecount!` is required because `linecount` is varying within the `block` (parenthesised sequence of lines) - and with `delayedexpansion` enabled, `%linecount%` yields the value when the block was encountered, and `!linecount!` the run-time or instantaneous value - as it changes within the block.

[Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947)

So - having established `#1`, `#2`..`#%linecount%` with the lines from the file, we can process those variables and produce a replacement file.

Note that there is a block formed by  `( for...%%e...)>filename`. This allows any `echo`ed data within the block to be redirected to the file. `>` redirects to a new version whereas `>>` would append to any existing file.

So - we iterate through all of the `#linenumber` lines using a `for /L` on `%%e`. For each of these, we set `%%c` to `"."` and `%%y` to `0` to `9` and then replace any string `%%y%%c` with `%%y` (`3.` gets replaced by `3` for example). Then repeat with `%%c` set to `","`. `set /?` provides documentation and browsing SO examples.

But Woah, Neddie! There's a little trick here. `,` is a list-separator so `(. ,)` won't work - it will be treated as `(.)`. Using the quotes allows `cmd` to read each character separately, and we need to use `%%~c` instead of `%%c` to dump the quotes.

So - take a look around. You can do a lot with batch if you're devious enough. And no doubt you'll be challenged if you present this solution. Be ready to explain it. A really good way to follow what's happening is to turn `echo` on and watch the magic step-by-step. Use `pause` liberally and perhaps remove the `>"%filename1%"` to prevent the report going to the file while you're observing what's happening.

Comment: Firstly, I would like to thank you for such a detailed response. It's working! And with your explanations I now have much better understanding of how to write batch programs and some little tricks of it - you really made my day!
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "verfile=%~1"

echo before:
type "%verfile%"

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%verfile%") do (
    set strline=%%a
    set strline=!strline:.=!
    set strline=!strline:,=!
    echo !strline!>>"%verfile%.tmp"
)

echo.
echo after:
type "%verfile%.tmp"
del /f /q "%verfile%.tmp"
```

Comment: Hmm. That will delete all commas and full stops, whether they are in a numeric string or not.